# Firebase Android - updateChildren owerwrites key-values in nested JSON structure

Tags: android, json, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried to find an answer about the following problem - found a couple in similar questions but cannot still solve it. If I flatten the structure it seems to work, but why?

basically - how do I add more key-value pairs in a json-object at Firebase WITHOUT owervriting existing ones?

let say I have the following jsonstructure

```
 "groups" : {
"aw" : {
  "members" : {
    "Lisa" : "true"
  },
  "name" : "aw university"
}
```

}

How do I then add more key-value pairs in members without overwriting existing ones? For instance, I want to add one more member - Magnus so the object becomes:

```
 "groups" : {
"aw" : {
  "members" : {
    "Lisa" : "true",
    "Magnus" : "true"
  },
  "name" : "aw university"
}
```

}

I have tried with updateChildren without success:

```
var hm = HashMap<String, Any>()
hm.put("magnus", "true");
database.child("groups").child("aw").child("members").updateChildren(hm)
```

What happends is that existing key-value (Lisa: true) is overwritten

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

the strange thing is that if the structure is flattened - updateChildren works and adds Magnus

```
  "groups" : {
"aw" : {
  "name" : "aw university"
},
"members" : {
  "Lisa" : "true",
  "Magnus" : "true"
}
```

}

But I want "members" to be a child of "aw"

Comment: That first line should do precisely what you want, as it is the exact equivalent of `database.child("groups").child("aw").child("members").child("magnus").setValue(true)`. Are you sure you are calling it on the right node? Is there any way you can add some more debugging information to show what is happening?

Answer (score -1):

Try this `database.child("groups").child("aw").child("members").setValue(hm);`